# How to left align following sub-elements to the right edge of the first child element?

Tags: css

I have the following HTML snippet.

```css
.entry{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.list_number{
  color: red;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.entry_body{
    border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
    <span class="list_number">1.</span> only before noun very great, or complete used for emphasizing an opinion, feeling, or statement
    <div class="entry_body">The way they’ve been treated is an absolute disgrace.<br/>
        I have absolute confidence in her.<br/>
        You’re talking absolute nonsense.<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I align `.entry_body`'s left border to the right border of `.list_number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to modify your code slightly, but I think I was able to accomplish what you are wanting using CSS grid. You can now use 1, 2, or 3 digit numbers or more for the entry list number

```css
.entry{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:  
    "number span"
    ". entry";
}

.list_number{
  grid-area: number;
  color: red;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.entry_body{
    border: 1px solid green;
   grid-area: entry;
}
.span {
  grid-area: span;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
   <span class="list_number">123</span>
   <span class='span'> only before noun very great, or complete used for emphasizing an opinion, feeling, or statement</span>
   <div class="entry_body">The way they’ve been treated is an absolute disgrace.<br/>
        I have absolute confidence in her.<br/>
        You’re talking absolute nonsense.<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for? I just gave `.entry_body` a `margin-left: 15px;` Also, your html is not correct, this sentence is not in tags, so I put it in a `<span>`: only before noun very great, or complete used for emphasizing an opinion, feeling, or statement

```css
.entry{
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

.list_number{
  color: red;
  border: 1px dashed gray;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.entry_body{
    border: 1px solid green;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
    <span class="list_number">1.</span>
  <span> only before noun very great, or complete used for emphasizing an opinion, feeling, or statement</span>
    <div class="entry_body">The way they’ve been treated is an absolute disgrace.<br/>
        I have absolute confidence in her.<br/>
        You’re talking absolute nonsense.<br/>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case I can't use fixed numbers. As the entry list number could take 2 or more digits, like `22.` or even `123.`. I could use a large enough fixed number but that will make the layout less pretty.

Comment: Okay I added another solution in another answer post.